# How can I change the position of a button in a form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and material-ui and I have a form with fields and a button. I'm not able to move the button on the right because I'm using: justify-content: "flex-start". I tried to define an other useStyles but doesn't work. How can I do?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#034563',
    '&$checked': {
      color: '#034563',
    },
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
    },
  },
});

 <form 
   className={classes.root} onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
   <TextField
     id="add-name"
     label="Name" 
     multiline
     value={enteredName}
     onChange={(event => { setEnteredName(event.target.value); })} />
   <TextField
     id="add-description"
     label="Description"
     multiline
     value={enteredDescription}
     onChange={(event) => { setEnteredDescription(event.target.value); }} />
   <FormControlLabel
     control={<Switch checked={isActive} onChange={ActiveChange} color="primary" />}
     label="active" />
     <div>
       <Box>
         <Button
           id="new-sumbit"
           type="submit"
           color="primary"
           variant="contained"
           autoFocus
          >
          Add
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
      <Box>
          <Button
            id="new-sumbit"
            type="submit"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            autoFocus>
            Add
          </Button>
      </Box>
  </div>
```